# MySQL query - how to remove variable data

Tags: mysql

I wonder if someone can help me please? I recently migrated from PHPBB forum software to MyBB software, but when the conversion finished I was left with lots of weird characters in many posts, such as `<P>, </e>`, etc.

I used the below query to remove things like this, and it has worked well and removed lots of these characters:

```
UPDATE mybb_posts SET message = REPLACE (message, '<P>', '') WHERE message LIKE '%<P>%';
```

My problem now is that the stuff I need to remove varies from post to post - here's a few examples:

```
">https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SUZUKI-DR-75 ... Sw7k9eIFHa</a><!-- m -->

">http://www.hagon-shocks.co.uk/catalog/c ... x?TypeID=F</a><!-- m -->
">https://www.moorespeedracing.co.uk/indi ... gKQjPD_BwE</a><!-- m -->
```

As you can see, each line that I need to remove starts and ends with the same group of characters. 
I modified the above query using the % as the wildcard, so the query became:

```
UPDATE mybb_posts SET message = REPLACE (message, '">htt%m -->', '') WHERE message LIKE '%">htt%m -->%';
```

When I click "Simulate Query" I get a message saying 1643 rows affected, but when I click "Go" to run the query it comes back and tells me 0 rows affected.

Is there something wrong with my query? Can anyone suggest how to fix it or suggest another query to achieve the same outcome?
TIA

Comment: Which mysql version are you using, further it is quite hard to guess what you have to change without seeing the original text and the exact result you expect

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Can you post some sample data (3 - 4 lines) so that we have something to run queries against? You could post a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=887f38568e63f05aa950e0f677a436ed) but be sure to post the data here also!

Comment: Some tasks are better done outside SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies.
The examples of text are shown in my original post, but I had to put the "code" formatting around them as the forum would not let me post without doing that. Here are the examples again:

```
">https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SUZUKI-DR-75 ... Sw7k9eIFHa</a><!-- m -->

">http://www.hagon-shocks.co.uk/catalog/c ... x?TypeID=F</a><!-- m -->
">https://www.moorespeedracing.co.uk/indi ... gKQjPD_BwE</a><!-- m -->
```

I want to remove this whole section of text, but as you can see the centre section (i.e. the www part) varies in each line.
It is MySQL 5.5.65
Sorry, I have no idea how to use "fiddle".